# IBM FileNet : com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCT0042E: TRANSPORT_WSI_NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

When trying to query FileNet with below query

> SELECT
> d.To,d.Cc,d.[From],d.Subject,d.[ReceivedOn],d.[SentOn],d.DocumentTitle,d.MimeType,d.StorageLocation,d.ContentSize,d.DateContentLastAccessed,d.Creator,d.LastModifier,d.DateLastModified,d.Name,d.Id,d.DateCreated
> FROM Document d WHERE   [ICCFrom]  LIKE '%xyz@gmail.com%'  AND
> [ICCMailDate] > 20210101T235959Z

> String query ="**Above query statement**";
> SearchSQL sql = new SearchSQL(query);
> SearchScope scope = new SearchScope(objectStore);
> IndependentObjectSet s = scope.fetchObjects(sql, pageSize, null, true);                   > // Get the page iterator
> PageIterator iterator = s.pageIterator();

I am getting the below error log.

> [INFO ] 2021-05-06 10.04.19.856 [Thread-158] [1571783]
> filenet_error.api.com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle 177- An
> exception has occurred while processing an executeSearch request. The
> search request is being retried(1) of (1) times.
> **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset**  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_272]    at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:1.8.0_272]
>
> Caused by: **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset**   at
> sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
> ~[?:1.8.0_272]
>
> Suppressed: **java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe** (Write failed)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_272]
>
> [DEBUG] 2021-05-06 10.04.19.858 [Thread-158] [1571783]
> filenet_tracing.api.detail.com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle 180-
> ***com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCT0042E: TRANSPORT_WSI_NETWORK_ERROR***: A network error occurred when
> processing a Web service request or response. See the nested exception
> for specific details. See full stack trace for details.  Message:
> Connection reset Duration 300,265 milliseconds.

Below is the java code I used to get instances of Objectstore.

```
// Get the connection
Connection conn = Factory.Connection.getConnection(uri);
// Get the user context
UserContext uc = UserContext.get();
uc.pushSubject(UserContext.createSubject(conn, username, password, getJAASStanzaName(configuration)));
// Get the default domain
Domain domain = Factory.Domain.getInstance(conn, null);
// Get an object store
objectStore = Factory.ObjectStore.fetchInstance(domain, configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.OBJECT_STORE_NAME), null);`
```

can anyone help me solve the issue.?

Comment: Could you please share how get you instance of objectStore and session? Connection URL?

Comment: Hi swepss , I have updated the main question of how I am getting object-store instance.

Comment: show me your uri (change hostname to @hostname@), FN installed to WebSphere? Are you using WSI or CORBA ? Is it on 9443 port or on 9080... your error looks like connection timeout cause of port unrecheable or may be you are trying to get SSL connection to non-SSL port. Gimme your URL ˆ)

Comment: Are you connecting from standalone JVM or under deployed WebSphere application?

Comment: I am using a WSI connection (http://hostname/wsi/FNCEWS40SOAP/)  and standalone JVM to Websphere through jace.jar.

Answer (score 1):

After some hassle, I found the link about session cache

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-long-ce-java-api-session-object-valid-once-its-instantiated-jav

I have cached the CE Java API session object in the map using objects hashcode.
And used it to retrieve resultset of files from object store without validating session object is valid or not.

So now instead of caching in the map. I am getting then and there when the object is needed. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default, WebSphere bind SSL port on 9443 please check the port.
2. Check protocol, I mean connection URL should be like https://host:9443/wsi/FNCEWS40SOAP,  try to connect using browser
3. Check JAAS stanza name, it placed in jaas.conf.WSI
4. Check VM params, it should contain link to jaas.conf.WSI

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="c:\Program Files\IBM\FileNet\CEClient\config\samples\jaas.conf.WSI"

non-Windows

-Djava.security.auth.login.config="/opt/IBM/FileNet/CEClient/config/samples/jaas.conf.WSI"
```

link to doc [Creating a Runtime Configuration](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=transport-creating-runtime-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @swepss. I have checked all the above. The problem was in the session object which has to be maintained programmatically. I have answered in solution how i solved it.